# What's the advantage of Google Chrome's strange setup strategy?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages of installing programs in AppData like Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639/what-are-the-advantages-of-installing-programs-in-appdata-like-google-chrome)

It will install itself somewhere in %HOMEPATH%. Why not in %PROGRAMFILES%?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always assumed this is to avoid forcing the user to have administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the most important reason is roaming. So if you logon to another computer in the same domain, you can have it there too (although roaming is not enabled in every domain).